# JMeter Aggregate Report in Grafana Dashboard using InfluxDB

Tags: jmeter, grafana, dashboard, influxdb

I want to create **JMeter Aggregate Report** in **Grafana Dashboard using InfluxDB**. I have created dashboard but it is not complete as **I am having issue with "Error %" column**. Could anyone please help me to create the same JMeter aggregate report in Grafana dashboard.

I have written below query for aggregate report in Grafana but it is not complete-

```
SELECT sum("count") AS "Samples", mean("avg") AS "avg", percentile("pct90.0", 90) AS "90% Line ", percentile("pct95.0", 95) AS "95% Line", percentile("pct99.0", 99) AS "99% Line", min("min") AS "min", max("max") AS "max", sum("countError") / sum("count") AS "Error %", mean("count") / $send_interval AS "Throughput", (mean("rb") / $send_interval) / 1024 AS "Received KB/sec", (mean("sb") / $send_interval) / 1024 AS "Sent KB/sec" FROM /^$measurement$/ WHERE ("application" =~ /^$application$/) AND $timeFilter GROUP BY "transaction"
```

[image: JMeter Aggregate Report]

[image: Grafana Aggregate Report Dashboard]

Comment: It seems your query is ok. Can you guarantee that "countError" columns have data for these particular rows and data type is same as "count" column? 

Check whether any errors in browsers console?

Comment: there is 50% error for all requests that I can see in graph. This 50% errors belongs to only DummySampler2 because I am explicitly doing that means all requests pass for DummySampler1 and all requests fail for DummySampler2. Here I am stuck with error% for individual request.

Answer (score 0):

I have Used two queries and merged the queries to get the results like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crchh.png)

Query 1 -
SELECT sum("count") AS "# Samples", mean("avg")  / 1000 AS "Average", min("min")  / 1000 AS "Min", max("max")  / 1000 AS "Max", percentile("pct90.0", 90)  / 1000 AS "90 %",  sum("count")/(${__to:date:seconds}-${__from:date:seconds}) AS "Rate" FROM "jmeter" WHERE ("application" = 'GrafanaIntegration' AND "statut" = 'ko' OR "statut" = 'ok') AND $timeFilter GROUP BY "transaction"

Query 2 -
SELECT sum("count") AS "error"  FROM "jmeter" WHERE ("application" = 'GrafanaIntegration' AND "statut" = 'ko') AND $timeFilter GROUP BY "transaction"

Then in Transform:

1. Add Merge
2. Add Field in calculation ->Mode - Binary operation, operation- error/ # Samples, Alias - Error Ratio
3. Add Field in Calculation ->Mode - Binary operation, operation - Error Ratio * 100. Alias - Error %
4. Organize fields -And Time, error and Error Ratio to be disabled

For Throughput(Rate) the test timing should be filtered when test started and ended.